# Unknown files in Home folder

Tags: macos, file-management, macos-sierra

I opened my home folder this morning and found a load of **greyed out** unknown files with weird names and dates.

Also my `Library` and `Trash` folder are greyed out although I can open them.

Please can anyone tell me what they are and how to get rid of them.

[image]

This is my device info

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The greyed out files means they are hidden files. Usually nothing to worry about, your OS is full of them.

Comment: might be useful to let the OP know how to hide them again.